# How to get URL of the images uploaded by Carrierwave to Amazon S3 via .ajax() jQuery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, amazon-s3

After uploading via carrierwave and jquery-file-upload. I need to access those files from javascript. I know it's easy to get those file with carrierwave's url method. But I need to get those URL via .ajax() method. Is there any workaround?

I can get the filename, but I need to get the upload path....

```
    $('.new_plotphoto').fileupload({
        done: function(e,data){
              var filess= data.files[0];
              var filenam = filess.name;
              console.log(filenam);}});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller action which responds to your snippet, you can add a `url` field to the json response which contains the url from carrierwave's url method.

```
@upload = Upload.create(...)
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @upload.as_json.merge({"url" => @upload.carrier_wave_url }) }
end

$('.new_plotphoto').fileupload({
    done: function(e,data){
          var filess= data.files[0];
          var filenam = filess.name;
          var url = filess.url; // NEW
          console.log(filenam);
     }
});
```